# Error while creating remote listener in service fabric stateful service (.NET Core application)

Tags: service-fabric-stateful, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

**Error:** Does not contain a definition for 'CreateServiceRemotingListener' and no extension method 'CreateServiceRemotingListener' accepting a first argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Below are the steps which I followed,

1. Created an interface that implements IService.

   `

   ```
       using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting;
       using System.Threading.Tasks;
       public interface IFileService: IService
       {
           Task<string> GetStringByName(string name);
       }
   ```

   `
2. Included following packages in stateful service named as FileService.

   `

   ```
    using System. Fabric;
       using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data;
       using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Collections;
       using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Runtime;
       using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime;
   ```

   `
3. Implemented IFileService interface in FileService.

   `

   ```
    internal sealed class FileService : StatefulService, IFileService
       {
           public FileService(StatefulServiceContext context)
               : base(context)
           { }
           public FileService(StatefulServiceContext context, IReliableStateManagerReplica stateManagerReplica) : base(context, stateManagerReplica)
           {
           }

           public Task<string> GetStringByName(string name)
           {
               return Task.FromResult<string>(name);
           }


           /// <summary>
           /// Optional override to create listeners (e.g., HTTP, Service Remoting, WCF, etc.) for this service replica to handle client or user requests.
           /// </summary>
           /// <remarks>
           /// For more information on service communication, see https://aka.ms/servicefabricservicecommunication
           /// </remarks>
           /// <returns>A collection of listeners.</returns>
           protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> 

       CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
               {
                   return new[] { new ServiceReplicaListener(this.CreateServiceRemotingListener) };
               }}
   ```

   `

Answer (score 3):

The [ServiceRemotingExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.remoting.runtime.serviceremotingextensions?view=azure-dotnet) class is located in `Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Runtime` namespace (that isn't included).

The important point to mention is that `CreateServiceRemotingListener` is **deprecated**. The recommended method to use is `CreateServiceRemotingReplicaListeners`.

Hope this helps.

---

**UPDATE 2019/01/28**

Here is the sample code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Fabric;

using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Runtime;
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting;
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Runtime;
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime;

namespace JustService
{
    public interface IRemotingService : IService
    {
        // Remoting methods
    }
    internal sealed class JustService : StatefulService, IRemotingService
    {
        public JustService(
            StatefulServiceContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
        {
            return this.CreateServiceRemotingReplicaListeners();
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that in order to use `CreateServiceRemotingReplicaListeners` extension method the service should implement an interface derived from `IService`.

Comment: could you give us an example?

Comment: @PrimeByDesign I have added a code sample to the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get there in the end but I'm sure this will help others.